# how to pass variable value to multiple url's using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

In following code i want to pass id as parameter to multiple url using ajax post method

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: root + "contacts/primary?json",
     data: { id: $(this).val() },
     success: function (o) {
          ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(o.primary),document.getElementById("contactPrimaryForm"));

      },
      dataType: "json"
 });
```

Then, How to do this..?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i correct understand your question you need this

```
$(function() {
 //first ajax call
 ajaxCall('url1' , data , callbackFunction1 );

});

function callbackFunc1(result) {
// second ajax call 
 alert('URL1 work');   
 ajaxCall('url2' , data , callbackFunction2 ); 
};

function callbackFunc2(result) {
    alert('URL2 work');   
}; 

function ajaxCall(url, usrData, callbackFunction) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    url: url,
    data: usrData,
    success: callbackFunction
});
};
```